# Summarize My Formula?

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

I would like to summarize my formula.
p and y are constant value, 10000 and 0.65.

When n = 3, my formula recalculate the result of n = 2. I don't want to recalculate. Is there way to summarize or other formula for that equivalent?

[image]

**Update :**

For More Info :

```
n=1 => 10000 * 0.65 = 6500
n=2 => (10000 + 6500) * 0.65 = 10725
n=3 => (10000 + 10725) * 0.65 = 13471.25
```

If I put n=3, I don't want to recalculate the result of n=1 and n=2.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.

Comment: @DannyBeckett. Who is telling about programming?

Comment: @DannyBeckett, U mean there is no way to summarize?

Comment: No, I mean what I said: Stack Overflow is a **PROGRAMMING** website! We have a separate site for [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @DannyBeckett. Thz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve such problems you may use the z-Transformation.
You actually need a value for x[0].

The result for x[0]=0 is:

x[k] = p*y * (1-y^k)/(1-y)

From your posting it seems that you need exactly that.

Comment: @Tabias, this equation is very useful for me. Thz for your help. Could you answer again here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599467/summarize-my-formula/599477?noredirect=1#comment1263007_599477

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a lookup table.

Whenever you need to calculate the X(previous) value, check in lookup table if it exists there. If not, calc and save it there, if yes, just fetch if from there.